# Соль и авторизация

Tags: php, авторизация

Ребят прошу помочь, в пхп ещё слаб. Сейчас появилась задача написать авторизацию, а как солить и т.п не знаю как правильно.

```
<?php
session_start();
// Подключаем функции
include ("function.php");
// Фильтруем и создаём переменные (POST)
$POST_login = filter($_POST['login']); // Прилетевший логин
$POST_password = filter($_POST['password']); // Прилетевший пароль
// Проверяем пришли ли данные
if (!$_POST['login'] or !$_POST['password']){
    echo 'Вы не ввели: <br>';
} else {
######### Д А Н Н Ы Е  П Р И Л Е Т Е Л И #########
    // Создаём mysql подключение
    // проверяем есть ли такой пользователь
    $mysql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name = '".$POST_login."'"); // Берём логин и пасс для проверки
    $mass1 = mysql_fetch_array($mysql); // Берём инфу в массивах
    // тут проверка 
    // Если пришедший логин равен тому который в бд, то ....
    if ($POST_login == $mass1['name']) {
        // Есть такой пользователь
        // Проверяем корректный ли пароль
        if ($POST_password == $mass1['pass']){
            // Пароль совпал
            // тут код 
        }
        if ($POST_password != $mass1['pass']){
            // Пароль не совпал
            echo 'Пароль не правильный!';
        } 
    } else {
        // Если в БД нет такого пользователя
        echo 'Пользователь с таким именем не найден!';
    }
}
########### Тут что конкретно не пришло ###########
// Не пришел логин
if(!$POST_login) {
    echo 'логин <br>';
}
// Не пришел пароль
if(!$POST_password){
    echo 'пароль';
}
?>
```

Comment: Готовые решения не подойдут? Нэ?

Comment: В базе храните не пароль, а хэш. Например `md5($pass)`. Соль о которой Вы спрашиваете это запись например в таком виде `md5($pass.'salt')`.  

    "SELECT * FROM people WHERE name = '".$POST_login."'"
Прямой путь к sql-инъекции. Все, что идет в sql запросы должно проверяться и перепроверяться.

Comment: Так соль добавлять надо при регистрации пользователя, а тут вы просто логините его.

Comment: это я знаю что надо хранить в хеше, мне просто говорили что нужно делать как то так: типа берём в хеш текущее время , добавляем этот хеш к взятому паролю и создаём сессию)

Comment: Ну судя по всему, вам пытались объяснить, как "солить" пароли от браузера к серверу. Потому, что иначе добавлять куда-то текущее время...

Comment: Тут, а особенно в ответе @Silverlce Вам уже много полезного сказали. 

Хочу добавить, что при ошибке аутентификации **никогда** не сообщайте в чем именно ошибка - неправильный Login или Password или,  допустим, база накрылась... Этим Вы помогаете взломщику.

В любом случае просто говорите Auth Failed.

Comment: >> Ребят прошу помочь, в пхп ещё слаб. Сейчас появилась задача написать авторизацию, а как солить и т.п не знаю как правильно.

На глаз и по вкусу :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Соль, это когда вы делаете не MD5(ПАРОЛЬ), а MD5(ПАРОЛЬ+СОЛЬ).
Задача соли - усложнить подбор пароля, подбором по хешу.
Есть словари, в которых прописаны отношения MD5(пароль) = пароль. Естественно такой подбор очень быстр. В случает со сложной солью все варианты нужно просчитывать. Если пароль сложный, и используется не MD5, а SHA1 - то задача становится грустной и медленной.

**Рассмотрим подробнее**

У вас в базе данных хранится не хеш пароля (кстати, пароль в открытом виде у вас там НИКОГДА не должен хранится, это... неэтично).
а что-то вида

```
$salt = substr(sha1($login), 10, 20)."\3\1\2\6";
$hashpass = sha1(sha1($pass).$salt);
```

Вообще принято соль писать в БД (отдельно, или в поле хеша пароля - не важно), но я предпочитаю именно такой вариант, так как если получат исходники, то точно получат БД, а вот обратное - не факт). Кстати использование непечатных знаков 3 1 ... , в случае, если противнику попадет только БД, без исходников - обеспечивает подбирающему много незабываемых часов)

При проверке ввода пароля пользователем повторяете такую же операцию.
Если хранить пароли обработанные так или похоже, а авторизацию делать через HTTPS - то в общем довольно надежно получается.

Солить также можно пароли передаваемые от браузера к серверу.
Через javascript-функции, но SSL конечно надежнее.

Comment: Спасибо за расширение кругозора о вставке непечатных знаках! ;)

Comment: Едва заметная склонность к security by obscurity :) Соль в любом случае усложняет атаку. 

В вашем случае, если нужно будет сменить алгоритм расчета соли, прийдется заставить всех пользователей заново ввести пароли.

Еще, разве не достаточно будет делать $hashpass = sha1($pass + $salt); Зачем лишний раз шифровать пароль?

Comment: Это дань параное. 

Вариантов-то три:

- использовать жестко забитую соль;

- использовать корявый алгоритм генерации соли;

- хранить соль рядом с паролем.

Обычно используют последний метод, но что толку солить, если соль "засвечена", в той же БД. На старом Core2 1.7 GHz тормозной РНР дает просчет миллиона MD5 хешей на одном потоке за 5.5сек всего-навсего. Если брать ксеон на 2х4 3GHz, это будет где-то 0.3 сек...

Comment: Ну, это означает только то, что подбор пароля по словарю сработает. Кстати, не думаю, что с SHA1 будет что-то другое. 

А миллион при переборе это меньше всех вариантов из 3-х байт (там 24  млн). 

Соль рядом с паролем спасает от подбора по **заранее просчитанной** таблице хэшей. Да, взломщик видит хэш и рядом соль. Но надо еще подобрать такую строку, чтобы она вместе с солью дала этот хэш. 

С другой стороны, вроде бы есть алгоритм подбора строки, производящий заданный MD5 за несколько часов. Читал, но реально не щупал. Склоняюсь к тому, что это **полуправда**.

Comment: не думаю, что с SHA1 будет что-то другое - можете не сомневаться, будет. 

PS:Для параноиков извращенцев - используйте sha512

Comment: Почему ? Намного дольше вычисляется ? Или просчитанных таблиц еще нет ?

Comment: Намного дольше вычисляется

Comment: Как по мне, какое бы ни было шифрование, взломщик все равно его достанет, если оно ему надо. Если не нужно никому, то даже простой пароль 123 будет лень подбирать. Я храню все в md5(md5()) и этого, думаю, достаточно.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, вычисления для 10000000 8-ми байтных ключей на Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5400  @ 2.70GHz программа на С

    SHA1 14817904 (usec)
    MD5 10734546 (usec)

Разница в 1.5 раза.